# How to get a password at session startup

Tags: r, passwords, rstudio

Currently where I work there is complex process for getting access granted to a projects working directory (requiring passwords to be submitted).  We have a series of scripts to grant access and are hoping to put them into the `.Rprofile` file so that they execute automatically when loading a particular project in Rstudio.  We are having issues though with how to get users to submit their passwords to the code when it is in the `.Rprofile`. For reference we work primarily on Rstudio-Server.

We tried putting `getPass::getPass()` in `.Rprofile` but this didn't take any input and just resulted in:

```
WARNING: your platform is not supported. Input is not masked!
```

Similarly we tried using `rstudioapi::askForPassword()` but this just results in

```
Error: RStudio not running
```

Is there a right way for getting the user to enter a password in the `.Rprofile` or is there another hook for running code once Rstudio has finished loading ?

Comment: Hi @gowerc did you solve it?

Comment: @NielsenRechia,  we did not :(

Comment: I just post me work around, maybe help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help someone

Create a `rscript` like below

```
if(Sys.getenv('PWD') == ""){
    cat('Wellcome!\n')
    pwd <- readline(prompt="Please, insert your password:")
    Sys.setenv(PWD = pwd)
    rm(pwd)
    cat("\014")
    cat("Right, everthing done for you, ", Sys.getenv('USER'), "!\n", sep='')
}
```

And source it on`Rprofile` like `"source('/usr/local/bin/rscript.R')"`

The user will se the wellcome msg, insert his password, and the script will save it as R enviroment variable `('PWD')` to be used later.